# Installing 14.04, getting "???" error

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, raid, bios

Windows user here trying to install Ubuntu onto a laptop that has no operating system to speak of. I got an external hard drive setup and it boots to Live okay. However, when I run the installer, it gives me a popup with a row of 6 question marks and will not let me continue the installation (or exit the popup). It occurs right around where you pick what timezone you're in, just after you hit the "Install Now" button on the options menu where you select whether you want to erase all partitions or do your own thing.

[image]

Comment: Which languages are used in the screens? Did you set any international settings?

Comment: @EliahKagan: Well crap haha. Thanks for showing me that. I am going to try it. And Volker, no I did not. I used the United States English version. I am going to try the link above and see if that works. Thank you both!

Comment: So I tried the technique from above and I still got it the "error", but now I can close out of it and it goes back to the partitioning window and never makes it to the timezone selection. Granted, the link describes trying to load along side Windows, which I am not doing.

Comment: Got it. Turns out it just doesn't like the raid configuration, so I had to go into BIOS, allow it to show the RAID setup, and then undo all of that. Now it installed fine. Thank you for all your help! :)