# Error "??? ???" while installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, windows, samsung

I'm installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in a dual partition alongside with Windows 8.1. I already have made room in the drive for Ubuntu with the Disk Management and left it unallocated. I'm booting from an USB stick. When the installer starts and I reach the "third party software" and "download updates while installing" but when I press continue it suddenly stops and shows this error "??? ???" along with an OK button and the installer just freezes.
I'm installing it on a Samsung Ativ book 6. I have look on other threads but they don't help quite enough and I'm still stuck trying to install it.
If anyone can help it would be great.

Comment: Exactly which other threads have you followed? In most cases, it seems to do with a RAID disk causing problems.

Comment: I followed this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/522195/installing-14-04-getting-error and also http://askubuntu.com/questions/455511/dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04-and-windows-7-on-fakeraid-installation-error-question-m . I guess RAID might be the problem but I don't really understand it quite well.